# A question on the partial sum of infinite doubly stochastic matrix

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, matrices, matrix-analysis, stochastic-matrices

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be an infinite doubly stochastic matrix. Is the following statement true ?
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij} >0
$$

Any reference or comment on this is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the down vote here. The question is quite clearly stated and may have been encountered in some research work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is no. Indeed, let 
\begin{equation*}
 s_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij},\quad b_n:=\frac{s_n}{n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}.  
\end{equation*}
Then $0\le s_n\le\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^\infty a_{ij}=n$, and hence we always have 
\begin{equation*}
 0\le\liminf_{n\to\infty}b_n\le\limsup_{n\to\infty}b_n\le1. 
\end{equation*}

After these preliminaries, let us give an example with 
\begin{equation*}
 \liminf_{n\to\infty}b_n=0,\quad \limsup_{n\to\infty}b_n=1. 
\end{equation*}
Let $A=\text{diag}\,(A_1,A_2,\dots)$ be a block-diagonal matrix, where for each natural $k$ the $k$th diagonal block $A_k$ is the $\ell_k\times\ell_k$ (permutation) matrix with $1$'s only on the secondary diagonal. So, letting $n_k:=\sum_{j=1}^k\ell_j$ (with $n_0=0$), we have $a_{ij}=1$ if for some natural $k$ one has $n_{k-1}+1\le i\le n_k$ and $i+j=n_{k-1}+1+n_k[=2n_{k-1}+1+\ell_k]$, and $a_{ij}=0$ otherwise. Then $A$ is doubly stochastic. 
Moreover, for each natural $k$, we have $b_{n_k}=1$ and hence indeed $\limsup_{n\to\infty}b_n=1$. On the other hand, assuming that the $\ell_k$'s are even, for $m_k:=n_{k-1}+\ell_k/2$ and $k\to\infty$ one has 
\begin{equation*}
 b_{m_k}=\frac{n_{k-1}}{m_k}\to0 
\end{equation*}
as $k\to\infty$ 
if e.g. $\ell_k\sim k^k$ and hence $n_k\sim k^k$ and $m_k\sim k^k/2$; so, indeed here $\liminf_{n\to\infty}b_n=0$.

Furthermore, since $0\le s_{n+1}-s_n\le2$, we always have the quasi-continuity condition $b_{n+1}-b_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. So, with a little extra effort, we can see that in the above example for each $c\in[0,1]$ there is an increasing sequence $(q_j)$ of natural numbers such that $b_{q_j}\to c$ as $j\to\infty$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Iosif. So the limit is not well defined. So it is more interesting to ask about the liminf: $ \liminf_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} >0$

Comment: Modifying the above construction (say using blocks of size $k^k$ rather than $2^k$), it is easy to make the lower limit $0$ and the upper limit $1$. That is, the ratio may oscillate anywhere between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Oh, I see. So indeed the lower limit can be zero. How about the following question: there exists a subsequence $\{n_k\}$ of $\mathbb{N}$, such that the subsequence has a positive limit, i.e., $\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{n_k}\sum_{i=1}^{n_k}\sum_{j=1}^{n_k}a_{ij}>0$?

Comment: If your original question was answered clearly enough and you have more questions, it is more appropriate to ask them separately. However, I have now answered your additional questions as well.